# How to store user's Location into the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gps, location

I'm working with ASP.NET web application i want to let the user to locate their location by using their GPS . i have done some research on this subject but the only suggestion i got is to let the user locate his location using Google maps and drop pin by himself and save it! also using `latitude` and `longitude`!

I want something like Auto-locator to let things become easier for the user ! anyone could help me how to do it ? also i'm confused about the data type i should chose for Location in the database table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [geolocation](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html) API that is avaible in javascript to retrive the users position.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show_map);

function show_map(position) {
  var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  // show pushpin on map
}
```

If you are using SQL Server you can use the [SqlGeography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.aspx) datatype to store the coordinate.